# Trying to rework the way my workbook works

Tags: vba, excel

Right now my workbook has one master sheet and 30-something individual sheets.  All the individuals are formatted exactly the same and just pull information for different departments within the company.  Is there a way, incorporating the macros I use to pull each department's information, to get rid of all the individual sheets for one template worksheet? I'd like to change it so that when I run the macro for a specific department excel opens a new worksheet based off the template and then puts the information that my current macro pulls into the new worksheet. What I use now to pull from the master worksheet follows:

```
Sub DepartmentName()

    Dim LCopyToRow As Long
    Dim LCopyToCol As Long
    Dim arrColsToCopy
    Dim c As Range, x As Integer

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute


    arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 3, 4, 8, 25, 16, 17, 15) 'which columns to copy ?
    Set c = Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("Y5")  'Start search in Row 5
    LCopyToRow = 10 'Start copying data to row 10 in DepartmentSheet

    While Len(c.Value) > 0

        'If value in column Y ends with "2540", copy to DepartmentSheet        
        If c.Value Like "*2540" Then

            LCopyToCol = 1

            Sheets("DepartmentSheet").Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=x1Down

            For x = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)

                Sheets("DepartmentSheet").Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).Value = _
                               c.EntireRow.Cells(arrColsToCopy(x)).Value

                 LCopyToCol = LCopyToCol + 1

            Next x

            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1 'next row

        End If

        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)

    Wend

    'Position on cell A5
    Range("A5").Select

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
        MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

I would like to insert something into this so that it opens a template and then posts the information exactly the way it does above.

Comment: Did you want to crerate a new workbook with the dept's info, or just copy a template sheet within the same workbook as the master list?

Comment: Basically the latter.  I want the workbook to contain two sheets at all times - the top sheet is the master, the bottom sheet is the template. Then when I run the macro for a particular department it should open a new(third) worksheet that looks and functions exactly like the template and pulls the information from the master sheet exactly the way it pulls it in my existing macro.

Comment: +1 for a very good idea.  Creating a single presentation sheet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT2: Option to remove all other dept sheets

```
Sub Tester()
    CreateDeptReport "2540"       'just recreates the dept sheet
   'CreateDeptReport "2540", True 'also removes all other depts
End Sub


Sub CreateDeptReport(DeptName As String, Optional ClearAllSheets As Boolean = False)

    Const TEMPLATE_SHEET As String = "Report template" 'your dept template
    Const MASTER_SHEET As String = "MasterSheet"

    Dim shtRpt As Excel.Worksheet, shtMaster As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim LCopyToRow As Long
    Dim LCopyToCol As Long
    Dim arrColsToCopy
    Dim c As Range, x As Integer
    Dim sht As Excel.Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Err_Execute

    arrColsToCopy = Array(1, 3, 4, 8, 25, 16, 17, 15) 'which columns to copy ?

    Set shtMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MASTER_SHEET)
    Set c = shtMaster.Range("Y5")  'Start search in Row 5

    LCopyToRow = 10 'Start copying data to row 10 in DepartmentSheet

    While Len(c.Value) > 0
        'If value in column Y ends with dept name, copy to report sheet
        If c.Value Like "*" & DeptName Then

            'only create the new sheet if any records are found
            If shtRpt Is Nothing Then
                For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
                    If sht.Name <> MASTER_SHEET And sht.Name <> _
                                                    TEMPLATE_SHEET Then
                        If ClearAllSheets Or sht.Name = DeptName Then
                            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                            sht.Delete
                            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                        End If
                    End If
                Next sht

                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(TEMPLATE_SHEET).Copy after:=shtMaster
                Set shtRpt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtMaster.Index + 1)
                shtRpt.Name = DeptName 'rename new sheet to Dept name
            End If

            LCopyToCol = 1
            shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown

            For x = LBound(arrColsToCopy) To UBound(arrColsToCopy)

                shtRpt.Cells(LCopyToRow, LCopyToCol).Value = _
                             c.EntireRow.Cells(arrColsToCopy(x)).Value

                 LCopyToCol = LCopyToCol + 1

            Next x

            LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1 'next row
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend

    Range("A5").Select 'Position on cell A5
    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
    Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
        MsgBox "An error occurred."
End Sub
```

Comment: I will fiddle with it more in the morning; meeting in 5, but right off I'm getting an error occurring message when I try to run it. I'll look at it more in depth tomorrow morning. Thanks for the quick response. :)

Comment: Finally had a chance to start looking at this and I'm getting "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" error for the first portion: Sub Tester()     CreateDeptReport "2540"

Comment: To prevent this comment thread getting tooo large maybe you could send your file?  email is in my profile.

Comment: Well, that will unfortunately have to wait until this evening. I'll have to recreate a simple version when I get home and send you that.  The only thing that would get me in hot water quicker for sending external attachments to outside addresses is probably trying to upload attachments from the local drives to a public email address to send out. Plus, most public email providers are blocked anyways. :)  But I'll write a note to do that tonight.

Comment: Ok ok. I know the comments are stretching out, but this one's worth it. I finally figured this out, and I've gotten it working so that it opens a copy of the template and copies the info the way I want. My one question at the moment -I'm sure I'll have more once I get this working :) - when it opens the copy it just names the worksheet 'Template(2)' since it's just copying the "Template" worksheet. How difficult is it to rename the worksheet within the macro?

Comment: EDIT: Is there a way to set up the workbook so that when I close it, all of the department copies are deleted? That way when I come back in to update the master sheet I can just run each department instead of having to delete each template copy that is created each time I run the macro?

Comment: Finally I'm feeling like this is pretty much where I want it to be; got a few more minor tweaks to the template, but that can be a separate thread.  I did add in a few lines to turn off the delete alert, but other than that it works well.

Comment: I am curious for future reference, the code above creates a new sheet for each department run through and it replaces the department sheets just fine, but it still keeps an individual sheet for each department. Others seem to like having each department now, but for future reference what would I need to modify so that when the macro is run it deletes any sheets other than the Master and Template and then creates the one worksheet for the department being run?

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you need:

```
Sub Test()
    CreateDepartmentReport ("2540")
End Sub
Sub CreateDepartmentReport(strDepartment)

    Sheets("DepartmentSheet").UsedRange.Offset(10).ClearContents

    With Sheets("MasterSheet").Range("C4", Sheets("MasterSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strDepartment, Operator:=xlAnd
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy Sheets("DepartmentSheet").[A10]
    End With

    With Sheets("MasterSheet")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    Sheets("DepartmentSheet").Range("B:B,E:G,I:X").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    MsgBox "All matching data has been copied.", vbInformation, "Alert!"

End Sub
```

Notes:  Instead of coping your template sheet to get a new presentation sheet, just setup your template sheet as you want it and the code above will clear the data on it before copying the new data to it.  And instead of only trying to copy specific columns, the code will hide the columns you don't want on your presentation sheet.

Comment: I like the idea, but it's causing one main issue with my template.  Above row 10 everything is frozen and contains various headers, merged cells, and summary charts.  Running your macro brings over the information just fine and filters out what I don't want there, but because it's hiding entire rows it is chopping up the top portion of the sheet (which I need there). :)  That's mainly why I was trying to work with what I had - it brings over the selected info but doesn't touch the frozen portion. Meeting in 10 but I'll pop back in before lunch and work on it while I eat. :)

Comment: The code does not hide any rows, I'm not sure what you mean by that.  The code can place the data where ever you want and leave which ever data you want.  You just need to let me know exactly what ranges you want left alone.  At the moment the code is copying the data to the department sheet row 10?  Is that what you want?  It does not alter any info above row 10.  If the problem is that its hiding the wrong columns above row 10 then you need to adjust the template to match the mastersheet or have blank columns that match.